# How to get collections in Trello API ?

Tags: javascript, trello

I need to get all collections of boards with trello API
here is a link how to create a collection and what is it
http://help.trello.com/article/1004-creating-collections-for-business-class-teams
and a link to documentation 
https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference , 
but i couldn't find a way to get collection of a board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added documentation for the current implementation of collections here: https://github.com/trello/api-docs/pull/110.

To create a new collection:

```
POST https://api.trello.com/1/organizations/{organizationID}/tags
```

with the parameter `name` which is the name of the collection you want to create. To see all of the collections that exist for an organization:

```
GET https://api.trello.com/1/organizations/{organizationID}/tags
```

To add a board to a collection:

```
POST https://api.trello.com/1/boards/{boardId}/idTags
```

with the parameter "value" which should be one of the IDs for the collections returned from the tags endpoint above. To see a list of ids of collections to which a board belongs:

```
GET https://api.trello.com/1/boards/{boardId}/idTags
```

Answer (score 0):

Trello team answered my question:

> Unfortunately, there's not currently a way to access collections via the API. I'll let our team know that this is something you'd be interested in...